# What does the acronym "btf" mean?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

What does the acronym "btf" mean in the following sentence:

> This project was a labour of love that took developers **btf** five years to
>   accomplish.

Comment: Meaning is essential to context. Where does this sentence come from? Who is the audience? What are the surrounding sentences? Without knowing this, it is impossible to say definitively whether it is an abbreviation, a name, a term, or a typographical error.

Comment: I am also curious what does the `btf` mean. I met the abbreviationg [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization). In that context (in a nutshell) the `btf` is used as a prefix to customize things. So, as the accepted answer suggests it may mean the name of a developer. But then it is not clear what will be the full form of the `btf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The abbreviation "btf" is the name of the developer.

It is not an [**acronym**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/acronym) because the abbreviation can't be used as a pronounceable word.

Some examples of acronym are

- NATO
- ASCII
- laser

Comment: Do you know those as developers? I can't find them....

Comment: @Lambie I found [this PDF](https://www.btfpartnership.co.uk/upload/pdf/panels/6_a.pdf) and also [this site](https://www.btfpartnership.co.uk/) although whether it is the *same* btf as in the question is moot. It seems clear from the context that "btf" is the name of the developer. If it meant something else, the sentence would probably have read "**_the_** developers btf..."

Comment: That's not a universally accepted definition of *acronym*, mind. Few people will observe the distinction between an acronym and initialism (simply because, by my lights, not a lot of people are familiar with the word *initialism* in the first place – https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym, quoting MWDEU, a reputable usage dictionary, appears to confirm that).

Comment: @userr2684291 indeed **Benelux** is an acronym, but is not formed from initials.

Comment: The questionable part is the pronounceable bit, but yes.

Comment: So was this downvoted because someone does not believe that btf is the name of developer, or because someone thinks an acronym is other than pronounceable? If you have a better meaning for **btf** please post an answer.

Comment: For the record, I have upvoted your answer because it looks like it answers the question together with the accompanying comment. Don't take downvotes too seriously. : )